# how feasible to embed phyton/matplotlib data visualation application in MS SharePoint site

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, sharepoint, pyside6

Currently i have a data visualization tool that i created using pythong and matplotlib - standalone application. i'm wondering how easy it is to embed in an existing SharePoint site.
appreciate all the feedback in advance.

at this point, i'm trying to understand the feasibility of this idea. from a usecase perspective, i expect the user to go the Sharepoint site and use the tool online the same as he/she would in the standalone version.

the tool is built in python using matplotlib, PySide6, and Qt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedding a standalone Python application into a sharepoint site will not be that easy, as sharePoint primarily supports web technologies for customization and integration. It also depends on what you want to visualize..
You can consider a few other options to make your data visualization tool accessible within a SharePoint site:

1. Convert your Python application into a web API and host it on Azure App Service. Then you can implement a sharepoint framework that interacts with the API hosted on Azure
2. Refactor your existing Python application into a web-based application using a framework like Flask or a web-based GUI library.Then host the web application on a server accessible from your SharePoint site.
3. If you're going to visualize charts or dashboards you might consider using Power BI

As I've already said, the choice of approach is heavily dependent on the complexity of the tool and what you want to visualize with it.

Comment: I may be wrong, but it seems like you're trying to answer using the output of a generative AI (probably ChatGPT). If that's the case, be aware that such contents are [banned on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831) and may result in account suspension.